# Difference between elastic limit and yield stress

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

I am having trouble understanding the difference between elastic limit and yield stress. I searched the internet for a few hours and found some conflicting answers. I have found 3 (maybe) different answers:

From the elastic limit to the yield point, the material is transitioning from elastic to plastic. This area is called the elastoplastic region. I got this conclusion from [here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/what-happens-from-b-to-c-in-this-stress-strain-diagram-of-mild-steel).

The yield point is the same as the elastic limit. The yield point is only found in the elastic point which is impractical to find precisely. I got this conclusion from [here](https://www.instron.com/en/resources/glossary/e/elastic-limit#:%7E:text=When%20a%20material%20is%20stressed,return%20to%20its%20original%20length).

The elastic limit is where the elastic region ends and the yield stress is just where a permanent deformation of 0.2% is formed. I got this conclusion from [here](https://www.quora.com/Are-yield-point-and-elastic-limit-the-same-point-in-a-stress-strain-graph) and [here](https://asrengineering.com/2019/08/14/the-stress-strain-curve-intro-to-structural-engineering/). This runs counter to what I am told by my lecturer which is that the yield stress is where the elastic and plastic region is separated.

So far, I have 3 answers answering the same question. Which one is the actual answer? Thank you

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/17919/10902

Answer (score 1):

There is not AN answer. Between 0 and 0.2% strain is a mixture of elastic and plastic. The 0.2 % is primarily applied to steels. "Yield" has both a physical and legal or practical definition. Most specifications for steel have a legal definition of 0.2% although some ( API) use 0.5% total strain as the definition.

Answer (score 1):

The elastic limit is **the range/region** of the material that behaves elastically in the stress vs strain curve. The yield stress is **a characteristic point** of the material, beyond which, the material is said to be out of its elastic range.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Elastic limit and yield point can be the same. For steels, there are 3 possibilities:

- clearly defined yield point $R_e$ without subsequent stress reduction
- clearly defined yield point with subsequent stress reduction, where upper and lower yield points, $R_{eH}$ and $R_{eL}$, are recognised
- yield point unclear, where 0.2 % or 1.0 % "proof strength", $R_{p0.2}$ or $R_{p1.0}$, become useful (usually high-alloy steels)

You can see the differences [here](https://studycorgi.com/tensile-testing-of-metallic-materials/#results). Some useful information might also be [here](https://www.zwickroell.com/industries/materials-testing/tensile-test/yield-point/).